# Evaluating a double integral that arises in computing the solid angle subtended by an equilateral triangle

Tags: definite-integrals

I was evaluating an double integral with following limits.

$$\Omega =\int_{-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}} \int_{-\frac{a-\sqrt{3}y}{3}}^{\frac{a-\sqrt{3}‌​y}{3}} \frac{a\,dy\,dx}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$$

(It's solid angle subtended by an equilateral triangle of edge "a" at a point on distance "a" from it's centroid)

I know that first i had to simply integrate it with respect to $x$. Took some time and give me the answer as:

$$\Omega = \int_{-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{a\,dy}{a^2+y^2}\left|\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{1/2}}\right|^{\frac{a-\sqrt{3}y}{3}}_{-\frac{a-\sqrt{3}y}{3}}$$

$$\Omega =\frac{2}{3}a \int_{-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{1}{(a^2+y^2)} \frac{(a-\sqrt{3}y)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-\sqrt{3}y}{3} \right)^2 + y^2+a^2}} \, dy$$

And well this is pretty much the ugliest integral i could get, I tried completing the square under radical and substituting further and etc . But no help. And I just hope I haven't made any careless mistake upto yet either.

Comment: There is an algebraic formula for the solid angle subtended by a triangle; see Van Oosterom, A; Strackee, J (1983). "The Solid Angle of a Plane Triangle". *IEEE Trans. Biom. Eng.* BME-30 (**2**): 125–126. http://www.researchgate.net/publication/16365809_The_solid_angle_of_a_plane_triangle .

Comment: Uh, I wish but I can not understand too much of advanced thing, I am still 17 , just out of high school. But I will try to take a look at it,

Comment: It looks like Wikipedia has the same formula in simpler notation, it's the first display equation in this section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron

Comment: Hmm nice! , Thank you! I will take a look into that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the solid angle we seek. It is actually not that hard to compute $\Omega$ by evaluating your integral in polar coordinates (see *method 1* below).

---

**Method 1** - direct integration in polar coordinate.

Rotate the figure $180^\circ$ with respect to the center. By symmetry, $\Omega$ is equal to

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_0^{\frac{a}{2*\sqrt{3}\cos\theta}} \frac{6a rdrd\theta}{\sqrt{a^2+r^2}^3}
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \left[\frac{-6a}{\sqrt{a^2+r^2}}\right]_0^{\frac{a}{2*\sqrt{3}\cos\theta}} d\theta
= 2 \pi - 6\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{12\cos^2\theta}}}
\end{align}$$
We can evaluate the integral on RHS as 
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{12} + \cos^2\theta}}
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{13}{12}-\sin^2\theta}}
= \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{12}{13}}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
As a result,

$$\Omega = 2\pi - 6\sin^{-1}\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}} \approx 0.3864229676956112$$

---

**Method 2** - [Oosterom and Strackee's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron) for solid angle.

Alternatively, one can construct three vectors
$$
\vec{p} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}   \\ 0 \\ a \end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{q} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{a}{2} \\ a \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\vec{r} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3}} \\ -\frac{a}{2} \\ a \end{bmatrix},
$$
normalize them and throw them
$\displaystyle\;\hat{p} = \frac{\vec{p}}{|\vec{p}|},
\hat{q} = \frac{\vec{q}}{|\vec{r}|},
\hat{r} = \frac{\vec{q}}{|\vec{r}|}$ to following formula of solid angle by
Oosterom and Strackee:

$$\tan\frac{\Omega}{2} = \frac{|\hat{p} \cdot ( \hat{q} \times \hat{r} )|}{1 + \hat{p}\cdot\hat{q} + \hat{q}\cdot\hat{r} + \hat{r}\cdot\hat{p}}$$

and get a different form of same answer.
$$\Omega = 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{9}{16}}{1 + 3\times \frac{5}{8}}\right)
= 2\tan^{-1}\frac{9}{46} \approx 0.3864229676956112$$

---

**Method 3** - external angle formula for geodesic polygon.

*Note* - I added this because I may reuse the Lemma below somewhere else. 
Feel free to ignore this.

Change coordinates so that the triangle $T$ at hand is living on the plane
$\mathcal{P} = \{ (x,y,z) : z = a \}$ and the reference point for computing
the solid angle is located at origin.

Consider following projection $\eta : \mathcal{P} \to S^2$:

$$\mathcal{P} \ni (x,y,a) \quad\mapsto\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}(x,y,a) \in \mathcal{S}^2$$

The $\Omega$ we want is simply the area of $\eta(T)$ on $S^2$. Under such a projection, straight lines on $\mathcal{P}$ get mapped to geodesics, i.e. arcs of great circles, on $S^2$. This implies $\eta(T)$ is a geodesic polygon.
[Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) tells us
$$\Omega = \verb/Area/(\eta(T)) = 2\pi - \sum_i \theta_i
\quad\text{ where } \theta_i \text{ is the external angle at } i^{th} \text{ vertex}.$$
What we need to do is figure out the external angle for $\eta(T)$.

Parametrize $\mathcal{P}$ by polar coordinates and $S^2$ by spherical polar coordinates

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
[ 0, \infty) \times [ 0, 2\pi) \ni (r,\phi) 
&\mapsto&
(x,y,z) = (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi, a) \in \mathcal{P}\\
[ 0, \pi ) \times [ 0, 2\pi ) \ni (\theta, \phi ) 
&\mapsto&
(x,y,z) = (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi) \in S^2
\end{array}
$$
Under projection $\eta$, the point with spherical polar coordinate $(\theta,\phi)$ on $S^2$ corresponds to the point with polar coordinate $(r,\phi)$ with $r = a\tan\theta$ on $\mathcal{P}$. Notice the metric on $S^2$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
d\theta^2 + \sin\theta^2 d\phi^2
&= \frac{(d\tan\theta)^2}{(1+\tan^2\theta)^2} + \frac{\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}d\phi^2
= \frac{a^2 dr^2}{(a^2+r^2)^2} + \frac{r^2 d\phi^2}{a^2+r^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{a^2+r^2}\left( \frac{dr^2}{1+(r/a)^2} + r^2d\phi^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
This means line segments parallel to and perpendicular to the radial directions
on $\mathcal{P}$ are scaled differently. Using this info, it is easy to derive
following

> **Lemma** Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $\mathcal{P}$ passing through $p = (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,a )$ and making an angle $\alpha$ with the radial direction. If $\beta$ is the angle between $\eta(\gamma)$ and the meridian passing through $\eta(p)$, then
>   $$\tan\beta = \sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{a^2}} \tan\alpha$$

Apply this lemma to our problem,

- At any vertex of $T$, the side of $T$ is making an angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$ with the radial direction.
- This implies its image under $\eta$ is making an angle $\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac13}\tan\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \tan^{-1}\frac{2}{3}$ with the corresponding meridian.
- As a result, the external angle for $\eta(T)$ is equal to
  $\pi - 2\tan^{-1}\frac23$.

From this, we find

$$\Omega = 2\pi - 3(\pi - 2\tan^{-1}\frac23) = 6\tan^{-1}\frac23 - \pi
\approx 0.3864229676956121$$

Yet another form of the same answer.

Comment: This answer was amazing. **. I wish I could +9000.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{blue}{\text{Solid angle subtended by any regular polygon}}$, having $n$ no. of sides each with edge length $a$, at any point lying at a normal distance $h$ from the center is given by the $\color{blue}{\text{generalized formula}}$ (derived in [HCR's Theory of Polygon](http://www.academia.edu/8747694/HCRs_Theory_of_Polygon_solid_angle_subtended_by_any_polygonal_plane_at_any_point_in_the_space_)) as follows $$\bbox[4pt, border:1px solid blue;]{\color{blue}{\Omega=2\pi-2n\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2h\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}{\sqrt{4h^2+a^2\cot^2\frac{\pi}{n}}}\right)}}\quad \color{blue}{\forall \quad n\geq 3}$$
As per your question, solid angle subtended by the equilateral triangle ($\color{blue}{n=3}$) having its each side $\color{blue}{a}$ at a point lying at a (normal) distance $\color{blue}{h=a}$ from the centroid is given as 
$$\Omega=2\pi-2(3)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2(a)\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}{\sqrt{4(a)^2+a^2\cot^2\frac{\pi}{3}}}\right)$$   $$=2\pi-6\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2(a)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\sqrt{4a^2+\frac{a^2}{3}}}\right)$$   $$\color{blue}{=2\pi-6\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\approx 0.3864229676956112 \space sr}$$