# How to find out the solid angle subtended by this slotted section?

Tags: solid-geometry, solid-angle

I have got to calculate total luminous flux incident on a plane section by calculating the solid angle subtended by the slotted (plane) section, having four identical rectangular slots each having width $5$cm & length $15$cm measured from the center $O$ (As shown in the diagram below) at the point $P$ lying at a distance $OP=6$cm on the axis passing through the center $O$ & normal to the plane of paper.

If the slotted section has inner radius $r=5cm$ & outer radius $R=20 cm$ then find out the solid angle subtended by this section at the point $P$ (lying perpendicularly outwards to the plane of paper)

[image: composite section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = 6$. Let $X$ be the slotted section and $Y$ be the slot.

Change coordinates so that $X$ and $Y$ are living on the plane $\mathcal{P} = \{ (x,y,z) : z = a \}$ and the reference point for computing the solid angle is located at the origin. The geometric setup is basically the same as in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281837/59379). 
Please read the **method 3** in that answer first, in particular the Lemma there. We are going to need it later.

For any geometric shape $Z \subset \mathcal{P}$, let $\Omega_Z$ be the solid angle
subtended by $Z$. Consider the projection $\eta : \mathcal{P} \to S^2$ as in above answer.
$$\mathcal{P} \ni (x,y,a) \quad\mapsto\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+a^2}}(x,y,a) \in \mathcal{S}^2$$
It is clear $\Omega_Z$ is simply the area of $\eta(Z)$ on $S^2$.

The key observation is under $\eta$, straight lines on $\mathcal{P}$ get mapped to geodesics on $S^2$.
So the boundary of $Y$ get mapped to a polygon of 16 sides on $S^2$ and $12$ of them are geodesics.

We will use [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) to evaluate $\Omega_X$ and $\Omega_Y$. In particular, we will use following version of the theorem on $S^2$:

> Let $\gamma$ be a simply closed piece-wise smooth curve on $S^2$. Let $\theta_i$ be the external angles at the discontinuity of $\gamma'$. The area enclosed by $\gamma$ is given by the formula:
>   $$\verb/Area/ = 2\pi - \left( \int_\gamma k_g ds + \sum_i \theta_i \right)$$
>   where $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature for $\gamma$.

If $D_\rho$ is a disk on $\mathcal{P}$ centered at $O = (0,0,a)$ with radius $\rho$, one can show that
$$\int_{\eta(\partial D_\rho)} k_g ds = 2\pi\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\rho/a)^2}}$$

It is clear $X \cup Y = D_R$ with $R = 20$, we find

$$
\Omega_X + \Omega_Y = 
\Omega_{D_R} = 2\pi \left( 1 - \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+R^2}} \right) = 2\pi\left(1 - \frac{3}{\sqrt{109}}\right)
$$

What's remain is to compute $\Omega_Y$. Since the inner radius $r = 5$ is the same as the width of the beam, the four curved sections of $\partial Y$ contribute  one-third of that of a full circle. Since $k_g = 0$ on geodesics, we find

$$\int_{\partial Y} k_g ds = \frac{2\pi}{3}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+r^2}} = 2\pi\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{61}}\right)$$

To compute the $16$ external angles, let us walk around $\partial Y$ counter-clockwisely.

- Eight of the external angles look like what happen at vertex $A$ (please refer to the figure below).

  The vertex $A$ is a distance $\rho_A = 5$ from $O$. The incoming curve is perpendicular to the radial direction while the outgoing straight edge is making an angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$.
  Using the Lemma in method 3 of the aforementioned answer, the external angle
  at $A$ is equal to
  $$
  \theta_A 
  = \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 + (\rho_A/a)^2}\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2} 
  = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{183}}{18}\right) - \frac{\pi}{2}
  $$
- The remaining eight external angles look like what happen at vertex $B$.

  The vertex $B$ is at a distance $\rho_B = \sqrt{15^2 + (5/2)^2} = \frac52\sqrt{37}$ from $O$. The incoming edge is making an angle $\tan^{-1}\frac16$ to the radial direction while the outgoing edge is making an angle $\tan^{-1}6$ to the radial direction. The external angle at $B$ is equal to
  $$\begin{align}
  \theta_B &= 
  \left( \pi - \tan^{-1}\left(6\sqrt{1+ (\rho_B/a)^2}\right) \right)
  - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac16\sqrt{1+ (\rho_B/a)^2}\right)\\
  &= \pi - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1069}}{2}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1069}}{72}\right)
  = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{1069}}{25}\right)
  \end{align}
  $$

[image: part of the slot]

Combine all these, we find

$$\begin{align}
\Omega_Y & = 2\pi\left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{61}}\right)
- 8\left(
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{183}}{18}\right)  +
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{1069}}{25}\right)
- \frac{\pi}{2}
\right)\\
\implies \Omega_X & = 
8\left(
  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{1069}}{25}\right)
+ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{183}}{18}\right)
\right)
 - 2\pi\left(
2 + \frac{3}{\sqrt{109}} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{61}}
\right)\\
& \approx 2.038049336500276
\end{align}
$$